# How to read QMnist label file?

Tags: python, deep-learning, mnist

[QMnist](https://github.com/facebookresearch/qmnist)
The label file is slightly different form MNIST dataset label file.
qmnist-train-labels-idx2-int.gz is 2D tensor, but I can't decode the label file to extract the class label.

```py
    f = gzip.open('./QMnist/qmnist-train-labels-idx2-int.gz','r')
    f.read(12)# skip 12 byte as document says
    buf = f.read()
    datalabel = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint32).astype(np.int32)
    datalabel = datalabel.reshape(8,num_images)
    print(datalabel[0])
```

The result is somehow correct but something is still wrong:

> [   83886080    67108864  1778909184 ..., -1525809152           0
> 0]

The last 2 items are 0, that's correct (item 6: duplicate=0, item 7: unused= 0). But, the first item is wrong! I can't relate this to digit 5.

Answer (score 0):

The function `read_idx2_int` in [`qmnist.py`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/qmnist/blob/master/qmnist.py#L187) does that.

```
import codecs

def get_int(b):
    return int(codecs.encode(b, 'hex'), 16)

def open_maybe_compressed_file(path):
    if path.endswith('.gz'):
        return gzip.open(path, 'rb')
    elif path.endswith('.xz'):
        return lzma.open(path, 'rb')
    else:
        return open(path,'rb')
    
def read_idx2_int(path):
    with open_maybe_compressed_file(path) as f:
        data = f.read()
        assert get_int(data[:4]) == 12*256 + 2
        length = get_int(data[4:8])
        width = get_int(data[8:12])
        parsed = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.dtype('>i4'), offset=12)
        return torch.from_numpy(parsed.astype('i4')).view(length,width).long()
```

For an even more general way to read mnist files, see function `read_sn3_pascalvincent_tensor` in [`torchvision/mnist.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/fa6af6d1e6f050d0a930e6f59894b7dd40aa869c/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L443).